# How to ensure that two procedures are never executed simultanously?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Procedure 1 checks document status and changes it to the next step.
Procedure 2 checks document status and reverts it by one step.

The issue: if accidentally the procedures get called simultaneously, procedure 2 changes the status first, and then procedure 1 doesn't execute as it should, because it gets the wrong status.

Is it possible to ensure that they never execute simultaneously for the same document?

Comment: Read up on database transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can set modules of the procedures with:

```
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE()
```

And then check whenever the module is running:

```
SELECT 1 
  FROM v$session
 WHERE MODULE = <your MODULE>;
```